# How to change your app to add Ads in Google Play?

Tags: android, ads

I'm in the process of putting my very first app on the Google Play Store. There is a setting that says "CONTAINS ADS".

Is it possible to change that setting once your app is fully submitted and is live on the Google Play Store?

Comment: Yes, you can change it later anytime, also you can manage almost all features like description, screen shots, ad contains, pricing all you can change later even if you have live your app.

Comment: @Vickyexpert Alright. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: any time enjoy your coding ..

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can change it in Google Play Console.
Under Policy -> App Content -> Ads

Select Manage

[image]

Select Yes or No.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Play Console and go to the App content page (Policy > App content).
2. Under “Ads,” select Start.